# How to inverse the function $\frac13e^x+\ln(3x+1)$

Tags: logarithms, inverse-function

What would be the strategy and final result of inverting the function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{3}e^x+\ln(3x+1)$$

Comment: It's very unlikely that there is an algebraic way to solve for $x$ here; so the inverse function will exist (since $f(x)$ is increasing), but there won't be a nice formula for it.

Comment: Why do you need inverse? There are applications where you don't need the explicit inverse

Comment: @Raffaele Out of curiosity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost impossible to find a nice formula, but simple to get a graph.

Once you have graphed $y=f(x)$ you simply draw the symmetric wrt the line $y=x$.

Hope this can be useful

[image]